# I am getting mismatch argument error on React native

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, objective-c, react-native

I am trying to build an iOS app written in react Native but it has a Native SDK bundled into it.

On the React native side I have this :-
The ***message*** is a text input field.

```
      <Button
            title="Is User Available!"
            onPress={() => {
            let value = message
           // Call method from Swift and wait for the callback response
              isUserAvailable(value, function(error, response) {
              let cscallbackmsg = response.cscallbackmsg;
              let cscallbackerror = error.cscallbackerror;
              console.log(cscallbackerror, cscallbackmsg);
              Alert.alert(cscallbackerror, cscallbackmsg);
              })
        }}
```

In the Objective C bridging module , I have this

```
RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(
                  isUserAvailable:(NSString*)value
                  callback:(RCTResponseSenderBlock)
                  )
```

And on SWIFT implementation I have this

```
func isUserAvailable(_ message: String, callback: @escaping RCTResponseSenderBlock){
      print ("about to execute isUserAvailable")
      nativeSDK.isUserAvailable(message) { (state, error) in
        switch state {
..
```

But while running the app I get this issue:

[image]

I am not sure there I am going wrong. I followed http://nightlyclosures.com/2018/02/09/writing-a-react-native-ios-module-in-swift/

and it worked but lately it's throwing this error.

Comment: Did you try clearing the Metro cache and rebuilding?

Comment: I tried with ````react-native start --reset-cache```` same issue persists .

Answer (score 0):

I changed the objective C class to below and it started working.

```
RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(
              isUserAvailable:(NSString *)value callback:(RCTResponseSenderBlock)callback
              )
```